# Customize link for add content

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

When I have a custom node type and I want to create a page, can the link be something other than what Drupal automatically assigns?

i.e. Currently to add a node-type it is: www.example.com/node/add/node-type

but can it be customized to just www.example.com/node-type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the path module, which is a part of Drupal core, to create a path alias. This will change the appearance of the url in the browser, but internally it will stay the same. You can find the settings at `admin/build/path`